# AppDelegate and TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote code as described below.

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .bold), .foregroundColor: UIColor.init(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)], for: .normal)

    return true
}
```

Then, I move to another Viewcontoller screen on one tab. At the same time, I wtore code as described blow:

```
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Then, I dismiss the ViewContoroller screen. Then, other tab text color have changed default color(blue). Why is this?

And the problem can be resolved by writing a code as described below:

TabBarViewController.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let color = UIColor.init(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .bold), .foregroundColor: color], for: .normal)
    tabBar.tintColor = color
}
```

I share a video about the problem to explain you clearly.
Please check it if you can.

https://streamable.com/z9d1j5

Comment: Are you testing with the actual device? Because some times simulator does not renders tint colour. Can you please explain what you are done with dismissing view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t configure selected color like this:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 9, weight: .bold), .foregroundColor: yourcolor], for: .selected)
```

Edit:

If you are running on iOS 13+ you should configure UITabBarAppearence like this:

```
 let tabBarItemAppearence = UITabBarItemAppearance()
 tabBarItemAppearence.normal.iconColor = UIColor.yourcolor
 tabBarItemAppearence.selected.iconColor = UIColor.yourcolor
            
 tabBarItemAppearence.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourcolor]
 tabBarItemAppearence.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourcolor]

 let tabBarAppearence = UITabBarAppearance()
 tabBarAppearence.inlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearence
 tabBarAppearence.compactInlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearence
 tabBarAppearence.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearence
 tabBarAppearence.backgroundColor = color
```

and then set the appearence like this

```
tabBarController.tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearence
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, it didn't fix.

Comment: I have edited my answer, does this works for you now?

Comment: Thank you so much, I can fix for your reply!